# golang DeepEqual and reflect.Zero

Tags: go, reflection

I'm trying to check if a field in a struct is set to its zero value with `reflect.DeepEqual`. The idea is that if it is the case, I can change its value with a default one given as a struct tag like following :

```
type struct {
    A int `default:"42"`
}
```

My problem is the following : It looks like `reflect.DeepEqual` is always returning me `false`. I think I'm missing something. Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    s := struct{ A int }{0}
    field := reflect.ValueOf(s).Field(0)

    fmt.Println(field.Interface())
    fmt.Println(reflect.Zero(field.Type()))

    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(field.Interface(), reflect.Zero(field.Type())))
}
```

And here is a go playground version of the code above : https://play.golang.org/p/k9VY-2Dc69

I would like to know why `DeepEqual` is returning `false` in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
reflect.DeepEqual(field.Interface(), reflect.Zero(field.Type()))
```

You are comparing an `int` value (wrapped in `interface{}`), to a value of type [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value). [`reflect.Zero()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Zero) returns a value of type `reflect.Value`, not `interface{}`.

You forgot to call [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) on the 2nd argument:

```
reflect.DeepEqual(field.Interface(), reflect.Zero(field.Type()).Interface())
```

This prints `true`. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fOYrAxsI1m).

Comment: This answer is a little better than mine, I think. In my playground I do a slightly more complex conversions to get an int, whereas converting to interface is, I think the right way to do it.

Comment: @BjornRoche If you plan to use the number, `Value.Int()` might be a better choice (as it handles more types while a type assertion only one), but for comparison I would avoid it, as it always returns the result as a value of type `int64`, even though the value wrapped in `Value` is of type `int`. And handing it over for comparison will implicitly pack it back to an `interface{}`, so no point...

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with your use of the reflect package.

```
field.Interface()
```

Returns an int (wrapped in an `interface{}`), while

```
reflect.Zero(field.Type())
```

returns an object of type reflect.Value. fmt.Println prints them both out the same way, but that doesn't mean they are the same type.

See this playground: https://play.golang.org/p/mLcLSV_0vA